# How to prepare soil for seeding?

Tags: lawn, soil, seeds, germination, repair

I have lots of weed in my backyard and I think I will seed for a green lawn! I was planning on installing sod but I think I will go with the seed. What should I do before I seed? Can I use weed killer and wait two weeks then seed then wait a week and use grub killer? Can I also seed my existing lawn?

Thank you

Comment: Sami, this is very similar to your first question (and thus may be closed as duplicate). I suggest you take the [tour], browse our [help] and read [ask]. And then you will probably want to [edit] this question. And: did you check for grubs? If so, how many do you have per square foot?

Comment: Yeah I will go head and delete this post. I posted this before I got an answer to another question. Thank you! No, I haven't checked yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using weed killer is of course the easiest option, but personally I am not a big fan of these toxic substances in your garden (maybe you want to grow vegetables as well in the near future, or you have kids or pets running around).

The old fashion way (people have been using it for thousands of years), is first plough up or dig up the soil. Weeds will be killed by this process. Then your soil is ready for the new seeds.

Comment: An answer to the (very similar) question suggests over seeding the bare and thin patches.